Prove that KLN is equilateral triangle
Given a triangle ABC with ∠ACB = 120◦
. The point L is marked on the side AB so that
CL is the bisector of ∠ACB. The points N and K are marked on the sides AC and BC,
respectively, so that CN + CK = CL. Prove that the triangle KLN is equilateral.
I've tried finding similar triangle or congruencies by doing some random constructions but nothing seems to work here .    I have not tried trignometry and other theorems , If possible can anyone one of you do it without trignometry? With or without please post your solution!!
This is the figure i have drawn and some constructions and tried finding congruent or similar triangles


It maybe not easy to understand what’s your exact attempts to this question. Can you edit your question by writing your full attempts with workings? Thanks.

Also, you can attach a picture for the geometry shape you have drawn for this question.

Sure i will attach the pics and constructions

Remember, only attach pictures for the diagram, for your attempts(working), you should use latex to type it out: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Thanks i am new here and latex at the start seems confusing to me atleast :)

In your question, angle $ACB$ definitely does not look like $120$ degrees.

Now that i think about it yea that doesnt even look close , ill try drawing a new figure. Thank you for your suggestion

Construct $X$ on $AC$ so that $LX\parallel BC$
Construct $Y$ on $BC$ so that $LY\parallel AC$
It is evident that $LXCY$ is a rhombus, and $LC=XC$
$XN=XC-CN=LC-CN=CK$
Along with $\angle LXN=\angle LCK=60^\circ$ and $XL=LC$, this shows that $\triangle LXN\cong\triangle LCK$
Thus $\angle NLK=60^\circ$ and $LN=LK$, thus showing that $\triangle KLN$ is equilateral.


Thank you for this solution. It was simple and amazing!

You’re welcome :) (Don’t forget to update your question image as mentioned in the comments)

To provide some motivation for this construction, let's analyze what it means for $CN + CK = CL$ to imply that $LNK$ is an equilateral triangle.   $\quad$
First off, there are a lot of possibilities for $CN, CK$. For example, we could have $CK^* = 0 $, for which $LCN^*$ is an isosceles triangle with vertex angle of $60^\circ$, hence equilateral. Similarly if $CN' = 0$. $\quad$ Since the angle at $L$ remains a constant $60^\circ$, this suggests that as we continually shift $(N, K)$, the triangles traced out by $LN$ and $LK$ (which are $LXN, LCK$ in OP's figure) must be congruent.

@CalvinLin Thanks a lot. I should also point out that the exact location of $A$ and $B$ are not needed for this problem. Rays along $CB$ and $CA$ and a fixed length for angle bisector $CL$ are enough. Thus we can mentally erase the line $AB$, which shows the mirror symmetry across $CL$.

I don't like the phrase "mirror symmetry across $CL$", because that's not what's happening. Rather, it's a "$60^\circ$ rotation about $L$", that brings $LXNC$ to $LXKY$, which is why those triangles are congruent.

@Calvin Lin As you, I was unsatisfied by the way the problem was formulated. Finally, I have found a natural way to handle it (see my answer) indeed by using (as you mention it) a $60°$ rotation.

@CalvinLin I didn't use the 'mirror symmetry across $CL$' for showing the $60^\circ$, instead, the mirror symmetry (along with the $120^\circ$ and it's bisector) can help one think about using the rhombus $LXCY$. After that it's just about observing the rotation about $L$, as you've already said.

Here is a solution which isn't fundamentaly different from the solution by @Soham Saha but

starts at once on a simplified figure (it has also been recognized independently by Solam saha).

uses a transformation (a rotation) in its final steps.


It is indeed immediate that we do not need points $A$ and $B$ ; the figure can be reduced, right from the beginning, to a particular rhombus $XCYL$ obtained by gathering two equilateral triangles $CLX$ and $LCY$ together (see remark at the bottom) :

Let $a$ be the common side of these equilateral triangles. Let $b:=CN$. As a consequence, because of constraint $CN + CK = CL$, we have $CK=a-b$ and therefore $KY=a$. Hatched triangles $LKY$ and $LNC$ having a same angle $60°$ between two of their sides with the same resp. lengths (fulfilling $"SAS"$ criterion) can be mapped one onto the other by a rotation with center $L$ and angle $60°$.
Consequently, we have $LN=LK$ with a $60°$ angle between the corresponding line segments ; therefore, $NLK$ is an isosceles triangle with main angle $\angle L$ equal to $60°$, otherwise said an equilateral triangle.
Remark : the presence of these two equilateral triangles forming the lozenge is natural : it is connected to the two extreme cases in the original formulation : when point $K$, resp. point $N$, is positioned on point $C$.

Here is the Geogebra figure where one can drag point $N$ along side $XC$.

+1 for the diagram (much better than mine) and the GeoGebra link.

@Soham Saha  : "Fair play" appreciated.

By law of cosines on $\triangle CKL$ and $\triangle CNL$,
$LK^2-NL^2\\=(CK^2+CL^2-2\cos60^\circ CKCL)-(CN^2+CL^2-2\cos60^\circ CNCL)
\\=CK^2-CK(CN+CK)-CN^2+CN(CN+CK)=0.
$
Hence, we have $NL=LK=a.$
We show that the quadrangle $CKLN$ is cyclic: Let $\alpha=\angle CLK$ and $\beta=\angle CLN.$ By law of cosines on the same two triangles above,
$$CK-CL=2a(\cos\beta-\cos\alpha.\tag1$$ By law of sines,
$$CK-CL=\frac{2a}{\sqrt3}(\sin\alpha-\sin\beta).\tag2$$
Hence, from $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$\frac{\sin\alpha-\sin\beta}{\cos\beta-\cos\alpha}=\cot(\tfrac{\alpha+\beta}2)=\sqrt3,$$
and thus $\alpha+\beta=60^\circ.$ Since $\angle KCL+\angle KLN=180^\circ$, the quadrangle CNLK is cyclic.
Finally, by Ptolemy's theorem,
$$aCN+aCK=CL.NK$$
$$a(CN+CK)=CL.NK$$
$$a=NK.$$

Sorry but could you explain a little more your application of the law of cosines ; I don't understand it. Besides, good idea to reduce the issue to the use of an inscribed quadrangle.

I agree with Jean about elaborating on the law of cosines. $\quad$ Also how do those 2 equal angles imply concyclic? They aren't on the same chord.

i am also i a little confused in this solution

Maybe, it is unnecessarily long. But, it is algebraic. You don't need genius pictures. @AvonShorts
